# Wrap axis labels in ggplot (including strings specified by labels argument)

Tags: r, ggplot2, stringr

I am using the following code:

```
ggplot(overall_vars, aes(overall_mother_protection)) + geom_bar() +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('Sangat Setuju', 'Agak Setuju', 'Tidak Setuju atau Tidak Setuju', 
                            'Agak Tidak Setuju', 'Sangat Tidak Setuju'))
```

to generate the following graph

[image]

Obviously I need to wrap that text at the bottom there, which I have done before using something like
`plot + scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10))`
However, I am getting hung up on the syntax here because, unlike in past instances, I am already using the labels argument of the scale_x_discrete() layer to specify a list of names (bc I want these names rather than the 1,2,3,4,5 factors within my dataset).

SO, my main question is: how do I write this code to **both** specify the label names, *and* wrap the text of those names.

One possible solution might be to just convert all the factors within my dataset to the corresponding character strings, but I would prefer to avoid this route.

(BONUS: another problem that I have run into that I am about to try to solve is the fact that for some of the variables for which I am creating this plot, there are 0 5's, which correspond to `'Sangat Tidak Setuju'`, the fifth label. I'd like the plot to show that label as well with no bar above it if possible. If you know how to do this, and want to go ahead and include that in your code for solving my other problem, be my guest!)

Comment: By the way, you could use `labels = scales::label_wrap(10)` instead of `labels = function(x) stringr::str_wrap(x, width = 10)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the variable to factor in the `aes()` call, which would free up the `label` argument. This should also cause the empty level of the factor to show on the x axis if you add `drop = FALSE` to `scale_x_discrete()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(stringr)

ggplot(
    overall_vars,
    aes(factor(
      overall_mother_protection,
      levels = 1:5,
      labels = c(
        'Sangat Setuju', 
        'Agak Setuju', 
        'Tidak Setuju atau Tidak Setuju', 
        'Agak Tidak Setuju', 
        'Sangat Tidak Setuju'
      )
    ))
  ) + 
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = 'overall_mother_protection') +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() + 
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10),
    drop = FALSE
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access and manipulate the breaks like this:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ str_wrap(as.character(.x), 10))
```

Comment: okay, that makes sense, but how do I include an argument for my label names there?

Comment: `as.character(.x)` converts the level name to string, if necessary